# OCaml's let polymorphism implementation

Tags: ocaml, type-inference, parametric-polymorphism

I'm confused about `let polymorphism` in `OCaml`.

Consider the following code:

```
A: 
let f = (fun v -> v) in
((f 3), (f true))

B:
let f = (fun v -> v) in
((fun g ->
    let f = g in
    f) f)

C:
let f = (fun v -> v) in
((fun g ->
    let f = g in
    ((f 3), (f true))) f)
```

For A and B, there is no problem. But for C, `OCaml` reports error:

```
Error: This expression has type bool but an expression was expected of type
         int
```

So for A, when evaluating `((f 3), (f true))`, `f`'s type is `'a -> 'a`,
for B, when evaluating `let f = g in f`, `f`'s type is `'a -> 'a`.
But for C, when evaluating `((f 3), (f true))`, `f`'s type is `int -> int`.

Why C's `f` doesn't have type `'a -> 'a`?

I have difficulty in understanding the implementation of `OCaml`'s
`let polymorphism`, I'll appreciate it a lot if anyone can give a concise
description of it with respect to the question.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is unnecessarily confusing because you're using the same name `f` for two different things in B and also two different things in C.

Inside C you have this function:

```
fun g -> let f = g in (f 3, f true)
```

Again this is unnecessarily complicated; it's the same as:

```
fun g -> (g 3, g true)
```

The reason this isn't allowed is that it only works if `g` is a polymorphic function. This requires rank 2 polymorphism, i.e., it requires the ability to define function *parameters* that are polymorphic.

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but you can have a record type whose field is a polymorphic function. You can then use this record type to define something like your function:

```
# type r = { f : 'a . 'a -> 'a };;
type r = { f : 'a. 'a -> 'a; }
# (fun { f = g } -> (g 3, g true)) { f = fun x -> x };;
- : int * bool = (3, true)

# let myfun { f = g } = (g 3, g true);;
val myfun : r -> int * bool = <fun>

# myfun { f = fun x -> x };;
- : int * bool = (3, true)
```

The downside is that you need to pack and unpack your polymorphic function.

As a side comment, your example doesn't seem very compelling, because the number of functions of type `'a -> 'a` is quite limited.